# Insert shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'm trying to make a code to help me insert a shortcode into the footer.
I succeeded with this:

```
function insert_scode() {
 echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" products ids="231,230,123,118"]');

}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'insert_scode', 10 );
```

Now, I want to make the inserted content responsive and also give it a class so I can customize it.
This doesn't work anymore:

```
    function insert_scode() {
 echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" products ids="231,230,123,118"]');
 <div class="scinsert" >
  <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
   <script>
      <html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       </head>
   </html>
</script>
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'insert_scode', 10 );
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not properly close and open PHP tag.
From your code.

```
function insert_scode() {
 echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" products ids="231,230,123,118"]');
 <div class="scinsert" >
```

You just call to HTML without close the PHP tag `?>`. This should showing the errors.

To fix this, close the PHP tag before send out HTML.

```
// I assume that you already have PHP open tag <?php.
function insert_scode() {
 echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" products ids="231,230,123,118"]');
?>
 <div class="scinsert" >
  <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
   <script>
      <html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       </head>
   </html>
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'insert_scode', 10 );
```

Comment: Yes you are right. But it still doesn't work. The products are inserted but do not become responsive. And the class appears after them. I tried this but it still doesn't work.

Comment: class scinsert {
function insert_scode() {
 echo do_shortcode( '[products limit="4" columns="4" products ids="7000,6955,6946,6901"]');
 }
}
add_action( 'get_footer', 'insert_scode', 10 );


$serco=new scinsert;
$serco->insert_scode();
?>

Comment: Responsive is about HTML and CSS.

Comment: From your code, you are trying to send out something that should be inside `<head>` mixed with something should be inside `<body>`. And `<html>` should be in the theme, on the top. NOT wrapped with `<script>`. Your HTML are really messed. This is the wrong way to response `<meta>` element.